# To create counter that is subordinated to another

Tags: counters

I have the following:

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \numberwithin{equation}{section}
    \newtheorem{Theorem}[equation]{Theorem }
    \newtheorem{Lemma}{Lemma }[equation]

\begin{document}
    \section{One}
    \begin{Theorem}
    Theorem one.
    \end{Theorem}
    To prove, use the following lemma
    \begin{Lemma}
    Lemma
    \end{Lemma}
    Observe we derived the following relation
    \begin{equation}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want that (1.3) to be (1.2.2). How to do?

Comment: There are better ways to achieve what you want. Can you provide a complete, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your current behaviour and also include the *expected* behaviour? It would really help make sense of your numbering scheme.

Comment: Is it clearer now?

Comment: @Werner I can't make the expected behaviour, that is why I want help from  experts.

Comment: It is clearer. However, the equation is not inside the `Lemma` environment in your code. Should it be? That is, should equation numbering within `Lemma` be different from equations *outside* a `Lemma`? Moreover, why should (1.3) be (1.2.2) and not (1.2.3) since you already have an equation (1.1) and Theorem (1.2) using that counter...?

Comment: Now that you have updated your question I see that my solution doesn't do what you want, but do you really want to do this? You have every lemma numbered with a theorem. What if the lemma is not naturally associated with a theorem? Also, how do you tell the difference between an equation that is numbered with a theorem and one that is not. To be more explicit, how do I know that the first equation is not numbered within a theorem but that the second one is?

Comment: That is why I need a second equation environment that shares the numbering with Lemma. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @WillM.: You need to *explain* the mechanism behind your numbering so that it makes sense. Once it makes sense, one can provide a general solution. The numbering scheme doesn't make sense as it stands... maybe it's just me.

Comment: The mechanism is:
Equation and Theorem have the same numbering: \thesection.\theequation
Lemma has numbering: \thesection.\theequation.\theLemma

I want an environment that does exactly what equation does but in lieu of \theequations, it uses \thesection.\theequation.\theLemma

Answer (score 1):

**Second solution based on edit to question**

Here is a relatively painless way of doing what you want by defining a new equation environment called `Equation`. This environment uses the `Lemma` counter to number the equations:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{Theorem}[equation]{Theorem }
\newtheorem{Lemma}{Lemma}[equation]

\makeatletter
\def\Equation{$$\refstepcounter{Lemma}}
\def\endEquation{\leqno \hbox{\normalfont \normalcolor (\theLemma)}$$\@ignoretrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \section{One}
    \begin{Theorem}
    Theorem one.
    \end{Theorem}
    To prove, use the following lemma
    \begin{Lemma}
    Lemma
    \end{Lemma}
    Observe we derived the following relation
    \begin{Equation}
      \text{Here is an equation}
    \end{Equation}
    \begin{Equation}
      \text{Here is a second equation}
    \end{Equation}
    \begin{equation}
      \text{Here is a third equation}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This almost certainly looks a little cryptic but, in fact, if you look in `latex.ltx`, one of the latex source files, you will find that the definition of the equation environment is:

```
\def\equation{$$\refstepcounter{equation}}
\def\endequation{\eqno \hbox{\@eqnnum}$$\@ignoretrue}
```

All that I have done is modify this so that it uses the `Lemma` counter (and it uses `\leqno` to put the equations on the left, as in the OP, and it expands the definition of `\@eqnnum` using `Lemma`).

One caveat, if you are using the [amstex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amstex) package then you probably want to do this a little differently because it does some fancy things at the start of equations. In this case, you will have added complications because you will want to do something similar with *many* environments like `gather`, `align`, ...

**Original answer** (more complicated)

I expect that there is a package for this but, if I understand your question, here is one way to do what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{Theorem}[equation]{Theorem}
\newcounter{subequation}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\Subequation{%
     \addtocounter{equation}{-1}%   undo increment of equation
     \addtocounter{subequation}{1}% increment subequation
     \RealEquation.\arabic{subequation}% print subequation label
     \xdef\@currentlabel{\RealEquation.\noexpand\arabic{subequation}}%
}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{Proof}[1][\relax]
  {\ifx#1\relax\relax\proof\else\proof[#1]\fi% start proof environment
   \setcounter{subequation}{0}% reset subequation counter
   \xdef\RealEquation{\theequation}% save current equation number
   \let\theequation\Subequation}% hijack \theequation
  {\endproof}

\begin{document}

\section{My wonderful section}
\begin{Theorem}
    1+1 = 2
\end{Theorem}

\begin{Proof}
  We analysize the fancy equation
  \begin{equation} 1+1=2 \end{equation}\label{first}
  and see that it must be true. It's so good we'll say it again:
  \begin{equation}\label{second} 1+1=2 \end{equation}
\end{Proof}

Outside of the proof the equation \eqref{second} is still true:
  \begin{equation} 1+1=2 \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

which produces the output:

[image]

The way this works is as follows. I have defined a `Proof` environment that changes the definition of `\theequation`, which is what LaTeX uses to print equation numbers. Inside the `Proof` environment `\theequation` becomes `\Subequation`. The `\Subequation` macro subtracts `1` from the `equation` counter (because the `equation` environment will increment this counter), increments a `subequation` counter and then prints the required label, e.g. `1.1.1`, and sets the current label in case you want to use `\label{...}` and `\ref{...}` with these equation numbers.

So, inside a `Proof` environment, which starts an ordinary `proof` environment, the equation numbers will be numbered as subequations of the current equation counter. This will not play well with nesting.

Comment: Can I ask you for a reference where to read how to create envirionments as the proof you made?

Comment: @WillM. 
 
Hmm, not really sure. Try doing a search for something like`latex \newenvironment tutorial`. The basic syntax is `\newenvironment{Env name}[number of arguments][default for arg 1]{code for start of environment}{code for end of environment}`. The stuff in square brackets is optional.